# Does each CALayer have it's own CGContextRef?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do hit detection on a CALayer containing a non-rectangular path. I am aware of the `CGContextPathContainsPoint` function but im not sure how to get a reference to the appropriate `CGContextRef` when I need to do hit detection (like mouse down). Is it safe to retain a reference to the `CGContextRef` that is passed to the `(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` delegate method for purposes of hit detection? I'm not sure if the same `CGContextRef` could potentially be modified by other layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the layer own a CGPath and hit-test that. Then you don't have to worry about whether it's safe to retain the context, and you don't have to re-plot the path every time, either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CAShapeLayer` instead `CALayer`, if you are dealing with drawing shapes over layer.
`CAShapeLayer` contains CGPath, so you don't need to maintain CGPath in your `CALayer`.